# Can selenium automatically detect text box on webpage and input values?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm a newbie to testing automation. By learning some basic selenium, I know I can use selenium tools to fill some forms online. Below is some code I'm using for your reference:

```
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Registration']")
elem.click()
iframe = self.driver.find_elements_by_id('frm_reg_load_patient')[0]
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_id("txtPatientLastName")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("Peng")
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_id("txtPatientFirstName")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("Richard")
```

And here's the screenshot of the web:

[image]

My question, is it possible to automatically find textbox and fill in some random values. I'm just testing if a new record can be created, so the values are not important.

Thanks

Comment: I guess what you are trying to ask is call a function which will search for all the `input` elements in the page and fill random data in it. Currently no such function is available in selenium, but I think you can create such function if required using selenium apis.

Comment: @kmal yeah. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Any idea on how to create this function?

Comment: You can read more about selenium and call a function which will get all `input` tag elements using one of the `find_elements..` method(You can also check if these elements are visible in your page or not). Then you can create a loop to go through each of them and enter some random/same strings to each of them. You should start coding, and ask new question here if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. In case anyone have same question:

```
//find all input fields where type = text or password and store them In array list 
txtfields.
 List<WebElement> txtfields = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='text' or 
 @type='password']"));

//for loop to send text In all text box one by one.
 for(int a=0; a<txtfields.size();a++){   
 txtfields.get(a).sendKeys("Text"+(a+1));  
 }
 Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"frm_reg_load_patient")))
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "txtPatientLastName"))).send_keys("Peng")
  self.driver.find_element_by_id("txtPatientFirstName").send_keys("Richard")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As per your comment update, your script/program will be more effective replacing the *implicit wait* with *WebDriverWait* but honestly there is no readymade `function()` available to *sweep the page to find any element* as such and *fill in random data*. Writing a new `wrapper` function will cater to your needs in a better way but that should be *out of scope* for this question.

Comment: thanks for the introduction of the module. The original code actually works without the implicit wait. I'm trying to find/build a function that can sweep the page to find any element like a text-box and fill in random data.

Comment: @WeiningPeng Please check the answer update and let me know the status